# What is the correct term for streams we substitute in a parameter?

Tags: parameter

Consider this code with my parameter:

```
for domain; do
    cat <<EOF > "/etc/nginx/sites-available/${domain}.conf"
        My \domain is ${domain}.
    EOF
done
```

Let's break the parameter in that code into parts: `$` + `{` + `STRWPAAIE` + `}`.

STRWPAA stands for "Stream to Replace When Passing An Argument In Execution".

In this case the STRWPAAIE is *domain* but what is the general term to describe it? It surely isn't STRWPAAIE (a term I just invented to describe what I mean), so what is the "formal" or "common" term to use here?

### Update:

I understand it is the STRWPAAIE is a variable, but it's not a variable in the general sense, rather, in quite a specific sense - a **parameter's variable**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a "variable". From `man bash`:

> A *variable* is a parameter denoted by a name.  A variable has a value and zero or more  attributes.   Attributes  are  assigned  using  the  declare
>   builtin command (see declare below in SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS).

Comment: @Arcticooling http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters